# Powrshell Set-AIPAuthentication returns "error":"invalid_client"

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have strictly followed the Application Registration for AIP Scanner detailed on the following link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/client-admin-guide-powershell#how-to-label-files-non-interactively-for-azure-information-protection

But every time i ran the following command I get an Authentication Error.

```
    Set-AIPAuthentication -WebAppId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" -WebAppKey "xxxxx/xxx/xxxx" -NativeAppId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    Set-AIPAuthentication : Unable to authenticate and setup Microsoft Azure Information Protection
    At line:1 char:1
    + Set-AIPAuthentication -WebAppId "eb10438f-d9bb-4cb1-946a-007223bcaaf4 ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Set-AIPAuthentication], PowershellException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.SetAIPAuthenticationCmdLet
```

On Fiddler I can see the following response when Authenticating against Azure AD

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: client_assertion or client_secret.\r\nTrace ID: 9859831a-e097-41df-933e-ead751464601\r\nCorrelation ID: 671215c0-0656-44bb-a4a9-fd1f4353fd37\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-10 14:35:53Z",
  "error_codes": [
    7000218
  ],
  "timestamp": "2020-11-10 14:35:53Z",
  "trace_id": "9859831a-e097-41df-933e-ead751464601",
  "correlation_id": "671215c0-0656-44bb-a4a9-fd1f4353fd37",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218",
  "claims": "{\"access_token\":{\"capolids\":{\"essential\":true,\"values\":[\"2016b1b4-bae5-44f2-abea-01dd12217771\"]}}}"
}
```

Which step on this guide I missed? and how do I troubleshoot it on Azure side? I can guarantee after 100 tests that WebAppID, WebAppKey and NativeAppId are ok. As far I can see it, I am not able to go further the first step on this OAUTH On-behalf flow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `AIPClient` Azure AD app is not Public client app.

**Public client applications** are applications which run on devices (phones for instance) or desktop machines. They are not trusted to safely keep application secrets, and therefore access Web APIs in the name of the user only (they only support public client flows). Public clients are unable to hold configuration time secrets, and as a result have no client secret.

Please see the 22th step [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/client-admin-guide-powershell#to-create-and-configure-the-azure-ad-applications-for-set-aipauthentication):

> On the **Register an application** pane, specify the following settings,
> and then select **Register**:
>
> **Name**: `AIPClient`
>
> **Supported account types: Accounts in this organizational directory only**
>
> **Redirect URI (optional): Public client (mobile & desktop)** and `http://localhost`

Make sure that you select "Public client (mobile & desktop)" for **Redirect URI**.

And you can go to the **manifest** file of the Azure AD app, in the **manifest** editor, set the `allowPublicClient` property to `true`.

[image]